# How to upgrade or downgrade migrations in Django?

Tags: python, django, migration, database-migration

I did migrations and I got some migration files like:

```
 - 0001_initial.py
   0001_squashed_0008_delete_userfolder.py
   0002_userfolder.py
   0003_auto_20200130_1454.py
   0004_auto_20200130_1512.py
   0005_auto_20200130_1513.py
   0006_auto_20200130_1514.py
   0007_remove_userfolder_sir_name.py
   0008_delete_userfolder.py
```

Syntax

```
python manage.py migrate app_name 0007_remove_userfolder_sir_name
```

Output

When I perform that downgrade migration it is not reflecting in the postgres DB

Comment: What's the error message you're getting when you enter `migrate` command?

Comment: What's in your `0008_delete_userfolder.py` migration? What should be reflacted in DB?

Comment: I have deleted user model But its not reflecting in DB.

Comment: When I give that                                                                                                       "python manage.py migrate app_name 0007_remove_userfolder_sir_name "    its not giving any error

Comment: Do you have the app in `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: When I give this command  "  python manage.py migrate application 0008_delete_userfolder "   It is giving this error   "  self.loader.graph.node_map[target].children
KeyError: ('application', '0008_delete_userfolder') "

Comment: @Tony Stark   :  Yes I have added that app name in INSTALLED_APPS